# Parse -getObjectInBackgroundWithId not saving on the database

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, parse-platform

I have a code snippet that will update information in the Parse database. I set up an action so that when the information is saved, it gets updated in the background. The function is being executed, but it's not saving anything on the database. its going through the function, but no changes are being saved. The changed values are inside a text field and a switch.

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"classnameinsave %@", self.productTitleField.text);
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.className];


    [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:self.productId block:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"inside getObjectsInBackgroundWithId function");
        NSLog(@"priceinsave %@", object[@"price"]);
        object[@"title"] = self.productTitleField.text;

        object[@"price"] = self.priceField;

        object[@"quantity"] = self.quantityField;
        object[@"show"] = self.show;
        [object saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if(succeeded){
                NSLog(@"Succeeded in Saving");
                      }else if(error){
                          NSLog(@"Error with saving changes %@", error);
                      }
        }];
    }];
}
```

Comment: It turns out the data is not saving because price and quantity are numbers, but are 'text' in the text field. How do I covert the text field to a number that is compatible with Parse back end?

Comment: Delete those fields on your DB.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this happened because the PFObject you're looking for doesn't even exist! You forgot to add the if statement for verifying if the object exists. Also, I understand you want to make it as dynamic as possible by having the class name based on a `UILabel`, but please don't do this, this doesn't make sense at all. Replace your code with this:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ClassName"];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:self.productId block:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    if(object){
        //Do everything here :)
    }else{
        //Display an UIAlertView to the user?
        NSLog(error);
    }
}];
```

Note: You *should* add the if statement, however it's not necessary.

Best regards,

Comment: This has nothing to do with what the OP is trying to accomplish. They are trying to update an object on the backend. Querying isn't the issue. The if statement isn't mandatory just good practice. Your implying that it's mandatory however. Even so if you were to check for an objects existence it would be `if (object) {}` your just checking for an error

Comment: @soulshined Done, now it's an `if(object)`. And no it has **nothing** to do with the back-end. The object doesn't exist. It already happened to me twice. If you have a better solution, then write one yourself.

Comment: The OP *thinks* it's a backend problem. But it isn't.